# Testing a thrown exception with JUnit in Gradle

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, junit

I use JUnit 5 inside of a Gradle project. I am trying to test this main function, in package P1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Gets command line arguments
    String fileName = null;
    if (args != null && args.length == 1) {
      fileName = args[0];
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please specify name of file.");
    }

    // Initializes file and scanner from provided path
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
      scanner = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("File not found: " + e.getMessage());
      System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Specifically, the try-catch block at the bottom. Here is the test I have written:

```
@Test
public void testMissingFile() {
    String[] args = { "bad_file" };
    FileNotFoundException thrown = assertThrows(
        FileNotFoundException.class,
        () -> P1.main(args));

    assertTrue(thrown.getMessage().contains("File not found:"));
}
```

Unfortunately, this test fails, with this output from `gradle test --info`:

```
TestP1 > testMissingFile() STANDARD_OUT
    File not found: bad_file (No such file or directory)
```

I am trying to catch this error and test that it is thrown, but instead it breaks the test. I was expecting the test to pass the assertions as they check for a FileNotFoundException and assert the contents of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching the exception in your code and printing the error message and that's exactly the result of the test, the output of `System.out.println("File not found: + e.getMessage());`

Your code is handling the exception, so the exception is not bubble up to the test.

If you want to test that it throws an exception, you should remove the `try/catch` block or throw another exception inside the `catch` block.